# Excluding a lot of results in Elastic cache?

Tags: elasticsearch

How I can do a query excluding a lot of results?

I think that I can't use:

```
"must_not" : { "multiples msg_id"
```

because it can be thousands of excluded items.

In SQL the query would be like this:

```
select m.* 
from messages as m 
left join msg_not_wanted as mnw 
on m.id=mnw.msg_id 
where user_id<>2;

CREATE TABLE messages (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
message VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE msg_not_wanted (
msg_id INT,
user_id INT);

insert into messages (message) values('a');
insert into messages (message) values('b');
insert into messages (message) values('c');
insert into messages (message) values('d');

insert into msg_not_wanted (msg_id,user_id) values(1,1);
insert into msg_not_wanted (msg_id,user_id) values(2,1);
insert into msg_not_wanted (msg_id,user_id) values(3,1);
insert into msg_not_wanted (msg_id,user_id) values(4,2);
```

Comment: Why not simply excluding the messages based on the `user_id` instead of the `msg_id`?  Basically, exactly what you're doing in your SQL query.

Comment: and put in the doc message all users (it would be hundreds of users) that don't want this message? I am not sure that this is a good solution

Comment: If each document is a message, then each document only has a single user_id, or do I miss something?

Comment: and then do I have repeted messages for each user?

Comment: It would be easier if you showed a sample document you're indexing and then we can see how to build the query you need.

Comment: I haven't decided the index structure yet. The problem is that I don't view clear that one document has an indeterminated number of elements in a array field (users that doesn't want view this messages)

Comment: Then show the DB schema you currently have and which use cases you'd like to support (e.g. search messages of users X, search messages for users Y and Z but not X, etc). There's always a way, but you need to explain clearly what you have and what you expect.

Comment: I have already writed my DB scheme and the query that I want to do in SQL sintax